# I have some issue while using UV editing

Tags: modeling

[image]

This is the first time I am using a blender, my model name is infant 3d modeling, while I am into edit mode my object looks like this and there are no changes in the edit. and the options for UV editing were not working.

Comment: it looks like you've selected an armature? An armature doesn't have any UV

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, I tried to transfer my blender file to unity 3D but there is no object in the unity once after I transferred. That's my Initial problem, In order to overcome it, I found that I have to unwrap my obj file in a blender.